# Which shopping cart software is used when the domain name starts with "shop."?

Tags: opencart, prestashop, shopping-cart, shopify

Are ecommerce sites using shop.xyx.com using a particular shopping cart software?
I've tried looking through their source code but I can't figure it out.
My guess is shopify. Ideas?

Comment: There's no connection between the domain name and the software that runs the site. They could be using anything.

Comment: You're probably not looking through their source code, that is on the web site.  Instead, you're probably seeing the HTML, Javascript and CSS.  In any case, there is not one answer to this question, web sites can use any shopping cart software they choose.  Please ask a question about a specific site.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm trying to find out what shopping cart companies are using to power a B2B online ordering system. Any suggestions? OrderBot seems promising.

Answer (score 0):

Domain is absolutely not related to the Ecommerce-Shopping cart Software used.
A Magento could be on shop.xyx.com, and a Shopify too.

Answer (score 0):

Try
http://builtwith.com/

To find out which framework/programming languages is used building that site (80% of time works for me )